# jQuery-focused textbox loses focus after one character of input in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, focus, jquery-events

I have a textbox that's being automatically focused with jQuery when an element is clicked:

```
my_item.find('input').focus();
```

It works in Firefox and Chrome as expected: the input area is focused and I can begin typing in it. In Safari the behavior is different though. I click the element, the input is focused, I start to type in the box, and it only lets me type one character. After the first character of input is typed, the input box loses focus and further typing doesn't work unless it's manually clicked for focus again.

I've found questions about `focus()` and Safari working strangely but I think this is a different issue. I've tried the solutions suggested there, such as `e.preventdefault()` on `mouseup` and similar, with no effect.

How can I get my focused text input area to remain focused while I'm typing in Safari?

Answer (score 10):

The question is a bit old, but i recently had the same problem so this is what i´ve found.
Check if your css rules blocks the touch callout.
If you have any rule like this try to remove and then try typing again

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

Comment: The problem in my case was actually -webkit-user-select:none;

Comment: Same here! Thank you!